# "-bash: !D: event not found" while writing command on putty

Tags: linux, bash, putty

I got a strange issue while writing a command on putty.

I want to download database from putty. I'm successfully logged in using private key and passphrase.
I have used this command to download database.

> mysqldump -u root -pjP+!D) foo > foodump.sql

I got the following error.

> -bash: !D: event not found.

I have so many special characters in original password. mysqldump , ls etc. commands working fine so I can't figure out issue in it.

I tried to login using WINSCP and run command in it's terminal and also open putty from WINSCP. But no luck for me.

Comment: have you tried `mysqldump -u root -p "jP+!D)" foo > foodump.sql` ?

Comment: you need single quotes around the password: `mysqldump -u root -p 'jP+!D)' foo > foodump.sql`

Comment: @arco444. I have tried with single and double qoutes also. It shows permission denied. And password is right. So may be it's considering qoutes as a characters of password. please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: try this: `mysqldump -u root -p jP+\!D\) foo > foodump.sql`

Comment: @FarhadFarahi. Thank you for your reply. 
 I tried with above scenario also but still it showing same error permission denied for this user. So I have to verify password after that I can conclude that error is in password or the password considering double qoutes as a character of password.

Comment: @FarhadFarahi. Thank you for your contribution brother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting single quotes around the password string:

```
$ echo 'jP+!D)'
  jP+!D)
```

Using single quotes, means every special character (except `'`) gets interpreted literally.

More here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html

Comment: Thank you. Perfect link for reference. It solved my problem. :)